# Probability (Independent Events?)

Tags: probability

I have no clue how to work out the two questions below, I would appreciate it if someone explained the method in detail.

---

Question 6: Probability

a) A couple move into a house. They wish to have a baby daughter. However they are told that the house is “unlucky” for girl babies as the last four babies born to couples at that house were all boys. Assuming that the probability of a baby being a girl is $0.5$:

i. What is the probability that the last four babies born there were all boys?

ii. Assuming that there 10 houses on this street that are for sale and that at all of them, at least four babies were born, what is the probability that at least one of the houses is unlucky for girl babies?

b) The independent probabilities that three components of a television set will need replacing within one year are $\frac{1}{10}$, $\frac{1}{12}$ and $\frac{1}{13}$. Calculate the probability that:

i. at least one component will need replacing

ii. one and only one component will need replacing.

---

I have tried:

a) i) $\dfrac12 \times \dfrac12 \times \dfrac12 \times \dfrac12 = \dfrac{1}{16}$

a) ii) $\dfrac{1}{16} \times 10 = \dfrac58$

b) i) $\left(\dfrac{1}{10} \times \dfrac{1}{12} \times \dfrac{1}{13}\right)\times  3 = \dfrac{1}{520}$

b) ii) $1 - \dfrac{1}{520} = \dfrac{519}{520}$

Highly doubt any of the answers above are remotely correct.

Comment: Can you at least write down what you've tried? Yes, having each kid is independent from the last.

Comment: edited original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) i) is correct. For a) ii), you're interested in the event that at least one house out of 10 had 4 boys born. You found that the probability of 4 boys is $p=1/16$, so the answer is then $1-(1-p)^{10}$, since $(1-p)^{10}$ is the probability that 4 boys weren't born in any of the houses.

For (b) i) you know the probability of no failure is $(1-1/10)(1-1/12)(1-1/13)$. Now look at the logic in a) ii). For b) ii), you need to exhaust all possible cases: first failed, second third ok; first ok, second failed, third ok; first ok, second ok, third failed. Surely you know how to calculate each case. The answer is the sum of these.